# Get user data by Alamofire before moving to homeView

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, synchronous, alamofire

I'd like to get user data using Alamofire before moving to homeView. At the following code, I want to call self.login() function after finishing to get jsonObj data.
Could you tell me how to do it? Thank you for your kindness.

```
@IBAction func signInWithTwitter(sender: UIButton) {

    Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { (session: TWTRSession!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if session != nil {

            func getTwUserData(completionHandler: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()){
                let parameters = [
                    "tw_id":session.userID,
                    "tw_name" :session.userName,
                    "tw_token":session.authToken
                ]

                Alamofire.request(.POST, self.uri.usersApi + "/tw_login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
                    .responseJSON { request, response, data, error in
                        completionHandler(responseObject: data as? NSDictionary, error: error)
                        var jsonObj = JSON(data!)
                        var uid = jsonObj["user_id"].int
                        self.defaults.setObject(uid, forKey: "uid")
                }
            }

            self.login()

        } else {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Update based on the Sash's advice.

```
@IBAction func signInWithTwitter(sender: UIButton) {

    Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { (session: TWTRSession!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if session != nil {

            let group = dispatch_group_create()
            dispatch_group_enter(group)

            let parameters = [
                "tw_id":session.userID,
                "tw_name" :session.userName,
                "tw_token":session.authToken
            ]

            Alamofire.request(.POST, self.uri.usersApi + "/tw_login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
                .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
                    var jsonObj = JSON(data!)
                    println(jsonObj)
                    var uid = jsonObj["user_id"].int
                    self.defaults.setObject(uid, forKey: "uid")
                    dispatch_group_leave(group)
            }

            dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
            print("4 seconds later...")

            self.login()

        } else {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw your function `getTwUserData` never gets executed

Comment: You should **never** do networking synchronously in an app. To the user, a synchronous request on the main thread looks like the app has frozen. Instead, you should make all requests asynchronously, and display a loading indicator, or something to that end.

Comment: Dear mattt
Thank you for your advice. Then, your advice is, I should display loading indicator function before self.login function?

Comment: In fact, I don't need to do networking synchronously. All I need is to finish networking before moving to the homeView. At login() function, it is moved to homeView

Answer (score 1):

There are many things to be said about turning asynchronous code into synchronous, especially in UI thread. I hope you have your reasons to do so:)

I don't think Alamofire has means of turning requests into synchronous.

However there are several ways to achieve it outside of Alamofire, one approach that should work for the most of the cases is to use Grand Central Dispatch groups:

```
let group = dispatch_group_create()        
dispatch_group_enter(group)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC * 4))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)){
    dispatch_group_leave(group)
}

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
print("4 seconds later...")
```

you should replace `dispatch_after` with your networking code and don't forget to `dispatch_group_leave` upon success and failure (if you have separate handlers).

Also keep in mind, there is a danger of deadlocking here: if you `dispatch_after` back onto main queue, it's currently busy waiting for `dispatch_group` to finish, that is why I'm dispatching into the default background queue.

Comment: Dear Sash
Thank you for your advice. I'd rewritten the code, but I cannot call login() function and  move to homeView neigher.
I've post the rewritten code at edit area, so could you check it?
Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see a reason not to move `self.login()` call inside of `responseJSON` replacing `dispatch_group_leave` (and dropping entire `dispatch_group` business). If user interaction is your concern, add a modal spinner that would indicate that you are still working but user can not interact with UI – it should prevent user from guessing whether app got stuck or still processing response

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's not good to convert asynchronous functions to synchronous variants, but if you really think you need and want to: I made a small library which can convert between them, including error handling with `throws` when the last parameter of the completion handler is an optional error type.

Check it out [here](https://github.com/Kametrixom/Swift-SyncAsync) (and read the disclaimer which explains when you should do this and when you shouldn't)

EDIT: It's a Swift 2.0 library, so it most likely won't work for you, sorry